# Identify Empty Folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to identify a specific empty folder in our user profiles.

I have a text file containing all of our user names that I want the script to refer to.  The script will loop each user directory and either output to file or screen and say if the directory is empty. Hidden files do not have to count!

Something similar

```
FOR /F %U IN (C:\UserList\UserList.TXT) DO *Find and List Empty Folder* \\Server\Share\%U\Target_Folder
```

Powershell solutions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730953.aspx) on Technet provides the following Powershell code snippet to identify all empty folders:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$a | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName
```

Replace "C:\Scripts" with the root folder you want to search.

**Update:**

The following script will get you in the ballpark.

```
$content = Get-Content C:\Temp\FolderList.txt
foreach ($line in $content)
{
    Write-Host $line -NoNewline
    $testObject = Test-Path -Path $line
    if ($testObject)
    {
        $folder = Get-Item -Path $line
        $filesCount = $folder.GetFiles().Count
        if ($filesCount.Equals(0))
        {
            Write-Host " - Empty folder"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host " - Contains files"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host " - Invalid path"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Bork.  I saw this snippet earlier and that will list all empty folders in the root directory.  This is fine but I want to be more specific and target one a folder in each of the user profiles

Comment: Works a treat.  However, is the $Folder.Getfiles().Count statement counting hidden files?

Comment: Documentation does not say. Should be easy to test though? :-) If it is counting hidden files, Get-ChildItem seems to offer more filtering options. I'll check it out later and if I find the answer I'll update the code snippet.